# Highcharts windrose

Tags: highcharts

I have created the following windrose using Highcharts:
[image]

Is it possible, instead of placing the "Frequency" and percentages along the "N" axis, to have it along the "ZZO" axis, since this will make the graph much more readable.

Comment: please put your code.. or give jsfiddle url

Comment: http://meteotoren.nl/meteodata/windrose.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rotation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.title.rotation) and use margin / offset / style parameter to position it, above ZZO.

Answer (score 1):

Put title in x-axis with following code.

```
xAxis: {
                    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                     title: {
                        text: 'Frequency (%)',                        
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        y: 250,
                        x:75,
                        layout: 'verticle'
                    },

                },
```

you will get text at near "ZZO"
[image]
you can change x and y value to get exact place.